# Omega theme node template renders outside any regions

Tags: 7, theming

The node template should render within the content region or at least should be replaced by the node template. But I am finding that it is not rendering within any regions, but it does rend within the content zone.

Now to be fair, Omega works correctly on a different site that I am working on. Just not here. At first I thought it was the sub-theme that was jacked. But I created a brand new empty one and it had the same problem. I also tried using the Omega base theme as the theme and had the same problem. So now I am at a loss as to what is causing this.

On my other site I tried to add the Delta module to see if that affected it, but no dice. So either another module is breaking it or something else is wrong in the config.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: We'll need to see some code to help you with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. It turned out I had the "main content" block visibility settings set to "Only the listed pages," but I had no pages listed in the box below.

So, (of course) it did not render.

Comment: I had to give the win to someone and it doesn't look I could give it to myself so you get it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turns out I was ignorant of a new feature in Drupal 7. Apparently you have to specify where the main content will go in blocks or context. If you don't then it will just put it where it can best find a place.